# can't see my drop down button on collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm new to learning bootstrap and am tryin to make my site a responsive nav bar. When I collapse the page, I can't see the typical dropdown hamburger icon but I still am able to click an invisible dropdown button in the center middle of my page. Any guidance as to how to change the nav dropdown icon color would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <!-- <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> -->
        </button>
      </div> 
      <div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mailing">Mailing List</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tour">Tour</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: give my answer a green tick its working

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of **navbar-toggle**, the class name should be **navbar-toggler**.
2. Insert a `<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>` into the button.
3. Give **navbar-** color and **bg-** color in your navbar.

code below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <!-- <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> -->
        </button>
      </div> 
      <div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mailing">Mailing List</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tour">Tour</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navbar-toggler-icon` (hamburger) in Bootstrap 4 uses an `SVG background-image`.

do these:
change `navbar-toggle` to `navbar-toggler`

change `data-target="##bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` to `data-target="#navbarNav"`

use `<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>` in between buttons tag

change  `<div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">` to
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">`

see this:
https://jsfiddle.net/30s62mfb/3/

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
   
   
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mailing">Mailing List</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tour">Tour</a></li>
        </ul>
     
    </div> 
  </nav>
```